# Insert multiple rows into SQL Server based on start and end dates

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I need to insert several rows into a SQL Server database based on `Start Date` and `End Date` textboxes.

E.G. `tbStartDate.Text = "25/12/2012"` and `tbEndDate.Text = "29/12/2012"` therefore I need to insert individual rows for the following dates:

```
25/12/2012
26/12/2012
27/12/2012
28/12/2012
29/12/2012
```

Please can you help me with the necessary T-SQL to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always there are a few ways. Here are some of them:

1. You can write code in your app that loops through the days and inserts a single record per day. (generally the worst design)
2. You can call some SQL script to do it all in the database.
3. You can wrap up your SQL script in a stored procedure and pass in the start and end date and get the stored procedure to do it for you.
4. You can cross join to a pre existing tally table and use it to generate your records.

If you can provide

-the version of SQL Server that you're using

-what the table looks like

-whether you're using C# or VB

then we can help further as it can be difficult to pass dates into databases. It can be particularly difficult if you do not validate them.

Anyway here is option 3 for you.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.t_test 
@StartDate DATETIME,
@EndDate DATETIME
AS

WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO YourTable(YourDateField) VALUES (@StartDate)
    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(d,1,@StartDate)
END
```

Then you need to call this stored procedure (called dbo.t_test) from ASP.Net and pass in your two date parametes as dates.

Comment: SQL 2012, Please see this SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b8f2e/6/0 for the Table Structure and I am using VB.Net

Comment: Well... you've already marked an answer as correct, but anyway you should probably think about what you want in all of those other non null fields when you are only supplying a date.

Comment: I have changed your SP recommendation to the correct answer as it is EXACTLY what I required!!! Excellent - Thank you!

Comment: Oh, thanks! I just realised I left a misleading comment in the comment so I've taken it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @Startdate datetime
Select @Startdate='20121025'
While @Startdate<='20121029'
    begin
      if not exists(select * from dummy where DATE=@Startdate)
        insert into dummy (date) values (@Startdate)
        set @Startdate=@Startdate + 1
    end;
```

Comment: This works perfectly using SSMS however I will be passing paramaters for a Start and End date from asp.net - I cant see a way to pass the End Date - Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @James, turn the above into a stored procedure with parameters startDate, EndDate and pass them in

Comment: @Greg - Thanks for the speedy response!! Im fairly new to SQL so not sure how/what to do