# insert number of rows based on start and end date

Tags: mysql

I found a code snippet for sql server and actually have to customize it for mysql while also passing parent table id (event_id).

SQL Server Version

```
CREATE PROC dbo.t_test 
@StartDate DATETIME,
@EndDate DATETIME
AS

WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO YourTable(YourDateField) VALUES (@StartDate)
    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(d,1,@StartDate)
END
```

MySQL Version Attempt

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `day` (IN start DATE, IN end DATE, IN event_id INT)
BEGIN
    WHILE start <= end DO
        INSERT INTO day(date, event_id) VALUES(start, event_id);
        SET start = start + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
```

My table day structure is

```
day (id, date, event_id)
```

Comment: So what issue you are facing?

Comment: hey tahir,,, good to see someone from khi :), well I kinda sorted it out in the attempt after several edits of my attempt and googling :)

Comment: good to hear that, you can answer your own question and it will be helpful to other too :)

Comment: well if you can help to improve based on this thread -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223599/insert-multiple-rows-into-sql-server-based-on-start-and-end-dates I'm trying to understand his point 2 and 4 in the answer.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: to see what good strategies are out there from knowledge point of view